# emailing a blog post to my blog using php?

Tags: php, email, blogs

is thier a way for me to send  an email to my php blog, and have it publish the blos post, i just find so much easier espcially using mobile.

thanks :))

Comment: can you specify your blog script? Is it custom? Wordpress?

Comment: i wrote myself, so yeh its custom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either:

- set up an email-address that pipes emails directly to a script (which is easy under most packages, but may require some low level access to the configuration)
- or use the excellent [`imap`](http://www.php.net/imap) extension in a cron job, polling a 'normal' mailbox.